# Python pandas resample timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with about 5000 rows and 17 columns. This is a timeseries with a frequency of about 60hertz (so 60 rows a second). I now want to resample it to a lower value (i.e. to about 40 or 50 rows a second). the first column is the timestamp in nanoseconds. Here's how it looks 
[image: dataframe]

The reason it starts at 60 is because I removed the first 60 frames (because of noise issues). 
When I try to set the index to datetime

```
df.set_index(DatetimeIndex(df['Timestamp'], freq='ns'), inplace=True)
```

I get the error

> {ValueError}Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency N

and setting the index to a datetime is requierd or else I get the error

> {TypeError}Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'

Answer (score 0):

`freq='ns'` is not a valid frequency string. 
Valid aliases are 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

I think you need to set `freq='N'`

If it is still not working, how about setting the value of `freq` to `'infer'` so that pandas will infer the frequency automatically.

Comment: 'ns' and 'N' are the same and to be sure I also ran it with 'N' and it gave the exact same error. Here's my source: http://benalexkeen.com/resampling-time-series-data-with-pandas/ (the second last table)

Comment: updated the answer. try setting `freq` to `'infer'`

Comment: infer is the standard param value so that does'nt change anything. Yet thanks for the answers